# Duplicating rows in one table based on duplicates in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables:

Request table:

```
Request_no  |  Request_ver_no  |  Sketch_no  |  Sketch_rev
------------+------------------+-------------+-------------
1000           1                  11-111                
1001           1                  22-222           
1001           2                  22-555   
1002           1                  33-333
```

`TFC` table:

```
Request_no  |  Request_ver_no  |  TFC_no  |  Sketch_no+rev
------------+------------------+----------+----------------
1000           1                  1          11-111
1000           1                  2          11-111A
1000           1                  2          11-111B
1001           1                  1          22-222
1001           1                  2          22-222A
1001           2                  1          22-555
1001           2                  1          22-555A
1002           1                  1          33-333B
```

My problem is that I need to fill in the sketch revision into the `Request` table, but there is more than one entries with unique sketch revision per unique `Request_no` and `Request_ver_no` PK.

A possible solution was to duplicate the rows in `Request` which has more than one unique sketch revision connected to it from `TFC`, and then implement a new index to differentiate these duplicates (Requests with only one unique sketch connected is set at 1 otherwise). For each duplicated `Request` entry the sketch revision (the last letter of Sketch_no+rev in `TFC`) is copied into `Sketch_rev` in `Request`. The index is also iterated and set for every duplicate `Request` entry.

For all the other cases without more than one sketch revision connected to the same `Request` entry, the revision is just copied over normally.

Ideally the end result would look like this:

Request table:

```
Request_no  |  Request_ver_no  |  Sketch_no  |  Sketch_rev  |  Index
------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------
1000           1                  11-111                       1
1000           1                  11-111        A              2
1000           1                  11-111        B              3
1001           1                  22-222                       1  
1001           1                  22-222        A              2
1001           2                  22-555                       1
1001           2                  22-555        A              2
1002           1                  33-333        B              1
```

(Blank is regarded as first revision)

TFC_no is not reliable as an index as there exists duplicates as well.

Where can I start with this query?

Comment: Just wondering, why are you duplicating data across more than one table? This violates third normal form. Do you have control over the database schema?

Comment: What is different here other than joining two tables on Request_No and Request_Ver_No (and then getting TFC.*, Tfc_No as Index, Request.Sketch_No)?

Comment: @HardCode Sketch+rev is not supposed to exist in the TFC table. I have control over the schema yeah.

Comment: @CetinBasoz The TFC_no cannot really be relied on either as there is alot of duplicate TFC_no as well. And the intent is to modify the Request table to contain sketch instead of TFC.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by TFC_No cannot be relied on. I will add one as a reply so you can review.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I edited the TFC table to better illustrate my point. There may be for example two TFC with same Request_no and ver_no with the same TFC_no (a result of somewhat uncontrolled data input in the past)

Comment: @KristianT, then how would you control the order? There is nothing that specifies an ordering in your tables. Also would you please provide your sample data as code (as in DbFiddle samples). And if that is the TFC, where does Index come from (without an ordering column)?

Comment: @KristianT, I edited my reply for a variation that does the ordering on Sketch_no_rev. While that is not a robust way, might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select r.Request_No, r.Request_ver_no, r.Sketch_no, 
   replace(t.Sketch_no_rev, r.Sketch_no, '') Sketch_rev, t.TFC_no [Index]
from Request r
inner join TFC t on t.Request_no = r.Request_no and t.Request_ver_no = r.Request_ver_no;
```

Here it is as a [DbFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7e025d1dbb8416f5327f98431d0c4f7)

EDIT: I am not sure if this might be what you meant, this one doesn't have a robust ordering column, but that maybe exactly what you want:

```
select r.Request_No, r.Request_ver_no, r.Sketch_no, 
   replace(t.Sketch_no_rev, r.Sketch_no, '') Sketch_rev, 
   row_number() over (partition by r.Request_no, r.Request_ver_no 
            order by t.Sketch_no_rev) [Index]
from Request r
inner join TFC t on t.Request_no = r.Request_no and t.Request_ver_no = r.Request_ver_no;
```

[DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5370a3a74ddb3e941fa34aeb189774d)

Comment: The TFC_no cannot be used for indexing due to amgiguity unfortunately, is there a way to increment a separate index for every duplicate?

Comment: @KristianT, it needs something for ordering. I used Sketch_no_rev which is not a robust one. There aren't any other options in your data as is (probably there would be datetime column which you could use).

Comment: This seems like exactly what i need, thank you!

The duplicated entries doesn't need any controlled ordering.

Answer (score 0):

would go with splitting column Sketch_no+rev with `left` and `right`, using the length (`len`) of the shortest record as indication of size of no review

(so that it can generalize to the case of having more than 1 character indicating rev version)

```
select Request_no
  , Request_ver_no
  , left([Sketch_no+rev], (select min(len([Sketch_no+rev])) from TFC)) as Sketch_no
  , right([Sketch_no+rev], len([Sketch_no+rev]) - (select min(len([Sketch_no+rev])) from TFC)) as Sketch_rev
  , TFC_no as [Index]
  from TFC;

select * from TFC;
```

SQL Fiddle on your data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e80d/4)